# Is there a funcion in C# to decrease the value of a int or double?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to make a script for players health stamina hunger and thirst. I am trying to make hunger and thirst decrease over time by 0.1 over a time of 3 minutes but i don't know if there is a function to do so (also i did the stamina as a int beacuse i want to keep it round). I am new to programing so it might sound like a dumb question. Here's the code i am working with.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Stats : MonoBehaviour {

    public double Health;
    public double Thirst;
    public double Hunger;
    public int Stamina;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Health = 100;
        Thirst = 100;
        Hunger = 100;
        Stamina = 100;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Comment: you should see Coroutines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to use a `coroutine`, like this

```
IEnumerator DecreaseStats(){
    float startTime = time.now;
    while(time.now - startTime < 3*60){ // less than 3 mins has passed

        hunger -= 0.1f;
        thirst -= 0.1f;

        yeild return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); // wait for 0.5 seconds (tweak this time)

    }
}
```

Then call this function whenever you want this decrease to begin

```
StartCoroutine(DecreaseStats());
```

This will run alongside your update method, and you can call it wherever you like in code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to keep track of time.

```cs
double time;

void Update () {
    ...
    time += Time.deltaTime;
    ...
}
```

Then you need to check if the time has passed

```cs
double targetTime;
void Update () {
    ...
    if ( time >= targetTime ) {
        time -= targetTime;
        hunger -= some number
        thirst -= some number
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand that you want to decrease Hunger and Thirst by 0.1 every 3 minutes, A specific function like that in C# it doesn't exist as i know but you can create one with the Sleep() method, Here is the code:

```
public static void Update (double health,double thirst,double hunger,int stamina)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            hunger = hunger - 0.1;
            thirst = thirst - 0.1;
            //Console.WriteLine("Hunger: "+hunger.ToString()+" Thirst: "+thirst.ToString());
        }

    }
```

It wait 3000 milliseconds (if you want 3 minutes you have to make it 3*60*1000 milliseconds), and then it decrease the two variables.
This is just a basic example you have to work on it and i think you must run it as a separate thread. I Hope i did help you & good luck with your game.